# Issues while compiling caffe with python support

Tags: python, boost, caffe

I got that error while trying to compile Caffe.

What can be the problem?

```
Linking CXX executable cpp_classification/classification
[100%] Built target classification
/PHShome/ez957/work/Feb10_2016_caffe/caffe/python/caffe/_caffe.cpp: In function ‘void caffe::Net_SetInputArrays(caffe::Net<float>*, boost::python::api::object, boost::python::api:
:object)’:
/PHShome/ez957/work/Feb10_2016_caffe/caffe/python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:131: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘caffe::Dtype*’
/PHShome/ez957/work/Feb10_2016_caffe/caffe/python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:132: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘caffe::Dtype*’
make[2]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/pycaffe.dir/caffe/_caffe.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/pycaffe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you cloned the last version of caffe? What is your OS? Have you applied any modification to the Makefile.config or just using the default setting?

Comment: Yes, I've cloned the last version of caffe. I'm running rh6.5, and not using Makefile.config, but cmake instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally succeeded by using boost 1.55 (instead of 1.59). I'm running

- redhat 6.5
- numpy 1.9
- Python 2.7.3